# Unable to find platform reset classification DLL

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino

Calling 'shutdown' suddenly outputs "Unable to find platform reset classification DLL", then it shuts down.

I am running QNX 6.6 for over a year, and this suddenly appeared.

Any ideas why this appears and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's failing on a dlopen of shutdown_nvram.so - it means that the shutdown reason and logs etc. will not be preserved in non volatile storage.